# Why does this loop execute only 4 times?

Tags: c

I am beginner in c programming.I just want to know why this loop is not working properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char x[8];
    char t;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &t);
        x[i] = t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It executes 8. White spaces are characters too.

Comment: @StoryTeller: 8 isn't an executable! ;-)

Comment: Use `scanf(" %c", &t);` instead of `scanf("%c", &t);`.

Comment: I want to take input from the user  that's why i am using scanf before x[i] = t;.

Comment: Before you write one more line of code, you need to learn how to debug.  Even just a printf("Here\n") statement in the loop would have shown that the loop was executing 8 times, and prinffing out the integer value of 't' would have shown why.  Using an actual debugger would have also been valuable - that's something that you WILL need with more complex apps.

Answer (score 3):

Because when any input given from keyboard we need to press enter to confirm completion of input.  This enter stay in buffer and if next input is char or string,  stores enter in string or char var and do not wait to input that char or string. In this case,  first input given at execution it stores char in X[0] and enter in x[1] and so on. So executes loop 8 time but it seems to 4 time because it ask input only four times.  To check that put one printf in loop

Comment: Thanks a lot @user8246589.

Answer (score 1):

it executes 8 times.
Whenever you press enter to submit, you are entering a whitespace character that is consuming one of your loop iterations.

Comment: A solution would be nice?

Comment: The question asked why. not how to fix, comments suggest it's an assignment/homework.

Comment: Then why answer if it isn't worth the bother?

Comment: This answer should have then been a comment!

Comment: But it _answers_ OP's question! "I just want to know why this loop is not working properly." "Why does this loop execute only 4 times?"

Comment: This answers the question, and by doing so is a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ryan.